# bootstrap3 align divs next to each other

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a form with username and password.
this is what i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

on small devices i want the inputs to be one above the other, on larger devices to be next to each other.

my problem is on the larger devices, when the inputs are next to each other and you get an error message, the password stays on the top (next to the error) and not goes down with the username input.

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row col-sm-3">
       <div class="username_input_error error_2_columns_right">
         <div id="username_error_placeholder" class="frm_login_errors error_msg" style="display: none">
        missing username
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_2_columns_left username_input">
      <input id="username" type="text" name="usernme" placeholder="Username" class="utility_bar_inputs panel_inputs" alt="Enter username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
    <div class="utility-bar-vertical-spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row col-sm-3">
    <div class=" username_input_error error_2_columns_left">
      <div id="password_error_placeholder" class="frm_login_errors error_msg" style="display: none;">missing password</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_2_columns_right password_input">
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="utility_bar_inputs panel_inputs" alt="enter password">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button id="perform_login" type="button" class="panel_button perform_login" alt="log in">LOG IN</button>
  </div>

<script>
  $('#perform_login').on('click', function (event) {
    $('#username_error_placeholder').show();
  });
</script>
```

[My example](http://www.bootply.com/o1mgR9FRjl) (click on login to see)

Comment: I think the password not goes down is not a problem. Because its top  position haven't content.

Answer (score 0):

How about just inserting a `<br>` element before the `username div`, I think it will give you what you want:

```js
$('#perform_login').on('click', function (event) {
  $('#username_error_placeholder').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="row col-sm-3">
    <div class="username_input_error error_2_columns_right">
      <div id="username_error_placeholder" class="frm_login_errors error_msg" style="display: none">
        missing username
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input_2_columns_left username_input">
      <input id="username" type="text" name="usernme" placeholder="Username" class="utility_bar_inputs panel_inputs" alt="Enter username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
    <div class="utility-bar-vertical-spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row col-sm-3">
    <div class=" username_input_error error_2_columns_left">
      <div id="password_error_placeholder" class="frm_login_errors error_msg" style="display: none;">missing password</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_2_columns_right password_input">
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="utility_bar_inputs panel_inputs" alt="enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button id="perform_login" type="button" class="panel_button perform_login" alt="log in">LOG IN</button>
  </div>
```

> Or just put the user and the password elements inside a `<p>` element.

Try it in your code, because the snippet doesn't show bootstrap CSS.